# drf-spectacular define request schema as JSON Array (like Serializer(many=True))

Tags: json, django, rest, django-rest-framework, drf-spectacular

Is it possible to define "many" serializer schema in `drf-spectacular`?

The request should take this data (JSONArray):

```
MonthlyIncomeSerializer(many=True)
```

Which is a list of objects/dictionaries:

```
[
    {'year':..., 'month':..., 'amount': ...},
    {'year':..., 'month':..., 'amount': ...},
    {'year':..., 'month':..., 'amount': ...},
]
```

I tried:

```
class PartialDTIPrenajomView(APIView):

    @extend_schema(parameters=[MonthlyIncomeSerializer(many=True)])
    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
```

which doesn't render anything in `Swagger`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`extend_schema`'s `parameters` argument is used for query parameters therefore it doesn't show anything on the POST method.

Changing to use the `request` argument should solve the issue.

```py
class PartialDTIPrenajomView(APIView):

    @extend_schema(request=MonthlyIncomeSerializer(many=True))
    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        ...
```